# in IOS CKCalendarView.in this calender how to disable future dates only

Tags: date, uidatepicker

how to disable future dates only.
I am using third party library  CK Calendar View click this link :https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar.
i am getting current and past, futures dates.in that library i am implemented all delegate methods.but i cant disable future dates.

Answer (score 0):

This question not seems to be detailed.. Any how something like the bellow code should may help..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ maxDate: 0 });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: i mean how to disable future dates. in ios

Answer (score 0):

when i use this code i solved my problem.in didselected date methode...

```
 if([date compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending
{
   NSString *today=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate date]];
    NSString *chooseday=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date];
    NSArray *date1=[today componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSArray *date2=[chooseday componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    if([[date1 objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:[date2 objectAtIndex:0]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Today date clicked");
        //_dateLblObj is my label object...
        _dateLblObj.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];           
    }
    else
    {           
        NSLog(@"Past date clicked");
    }
}
else{
    NSLog(@"future date clicked");
}
```